# Preventing access to TTY when X is killed

Tags: xorg, security, console, screen-lock

Assume I start an X server manually from a virtual console `/dev/tty1` with `xinit` or `startx`, with the line `id:3:initdefault:` set in `/etc/inittab`. The X server gets run and put on another virtual console, normally being `/dev/tty7`. After some time I decide to lock the screen with `xscreensaver --lock` and leave my computer. To unlock the screen one would have to know my user's password. 
If someone now decides to kill the running X server, he or she would be returned to the shell running at `/dev/tty1` and pretty much have access to my computer. Typically, the X server can be killed with `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` or switching to the initial console and `SIGTERM` the running process with `^C`.

This is trivial to do - which means there must be trivial ways to prevent it from happening. I'm using [`vlock`](http://freecode.com/projects/vlock) to lock my virtual console `/dev/tty1` to prevent this:

```
$ xinit && vlock || vlock
```

When the X server now returns, gracefully `&&` or not `||`, the console will be locked. This may not be the optimal solution.
I've read [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=794935) thread and [this](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/TIP_Fix_The_Login_Security_Hole) wiki article, explaining different solutions.

What other methods are there to prevent this kind of access to virtual consoles from X sessions? Is the above method safe enough? How do you prevent this on your system? I'm not going to use a display manager.

Comment: I just use `startx & vlock`.  `&&` and `||` wait for the previous process to terminate (possible race condition with keyboard interrupt Ctrl-c).  You should also remember that physical access is game over as far as security goes, as anyone could pop in a tiny surreptitious keylogger or do any number of other things while you are away.  I generally take the position of either giving up on security/trusting everyone who has physical access to my computer OR physically securing my computer (e.g. by keeping it with me) if I actually need my computer secured.

Comment: Have you considered `vlock -na`? That blocks the *entire* "console display" (`-a`), so you can't switch to other VTs. `-n` creates a new VT for `vlock`, making it possible to use it from X. With this, you'd run `vlock -na` instead of `xscreensaver --lock`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can prevent console switches from Xorg by adding the [`Option
"DontVTSwitch" "yes"`](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Desktop_Deployment_Guide/s1-ddg-lockdown-disable-command-line.html) to your Xorg config file.

To prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> you have to
add the [`DontZap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/xorg.conf.5.html) option to your Xorg config file. Of course this will not completely prevent access to the console. If `X` terminates for some reason, e.g. problem with a driver the attacker will still have access to your console.

You can also use `exec startx` instead of `startx` which will replaces bash with startx, this means even if someone is able to abort `X` they won't be able to access your console. You can also use a display manager like `lightdm`, `kdm`, `gdm`, or `xdm` so you won't need an existing shell session to start a x session.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following entry in my `.profile`:

```
# startx if on tty1 and tmux on tty2
if [[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]] && [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]]; then
    exec xinit -- :0 -novtswitch &>/dev/null &
    logout

  elif [[ $(tty) = /dev/tty2 ]]; then
    tmux -f $HOME/.tmux/conf new -s secured
fi
```

If I choose to log into `X`, I use TTY1. The `logout` ensures that, after `X` is started on TTY7, I am logged out of TTY1. I use [xautolock](http://freecode.com/projects/xautolock) and [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) as my screen locking tools.

If `X` is killed, I am dumped back to an empty TTY7 and then have to switch to one of six active gettys to log back in.

Comment: why the extra `logout` after `exec`?

Comment: One word: paranoia...

Comment: @UlrichDangel The only `exec` here is in a subshell.