# Most minimalistic way to switch users in X session

Tags: xorg, xmonad, display-manager

If I want a minimalistic login I can use something like this in my `.zprofile`:

```
if [ $(tty) = "/dev/tty1" ]; then
startx
fi
```

However doing this way I cannot switch users on the fly anymore. I.e. lock one X session without logging out and switch to the X session of another user.

What's the most minimalistic way get this work this? For example I don't want to use a heavyweight display manager like gdm or kdm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "most minimalistic" way would be to use a lightweight screenlocker like [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) or [i3lock](http://i3wm.org/i3lock/) and have a profile for your second user that starts their session from a different TTY:

```
if [ $(tty) = "/dev/tty2" ]; then
    exec startx -- vt2 &>/dev/null
    logout
fi
```

You would then just have to lock your session (bind `slock` to a keybind or have [xautolock](http://freecode.com/projects/xautolock) trigger it after a period of inactivity) and switch to TTY2 and start a session for User2.

Comment: Another: vlock. There are a bunch of these.

Comment: @dubiousjim Indeed.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/preventing-access-to-tty-when-x-is-killed

Answer (score 0):

Never fear, [cdm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CDM) is here. (Was in an Underdog mood.)

Comment: Is there an ubuntu ppa for this?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Ubuntu. It's just a few shell scripts and config files. Should be easy enough to install by hand.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this will suit your needs after all. It's just a minimalistic startup manager. It doesn't give you anyway to lock X sessions and switch to another user. This is accomplishable, by starting two X servers on different virtual terminals. You can then switch between them using ctrl-alt-F6/F7 or whatever. But there's no "locking" provided for the X server you're not using. And cdm doesn't do anything to help you do this; you'd have to do it on your own. Sorry, I read your whole question but for some reason just replied to the "minimalistic startup manager" part of it.