# How to prevent killing the X server with CTRL+C using bash traps?

Tags: bash, session, x-server

On my Debian Wheezy system, I used to start my X session with the startx command.

My .xinitrc file is:

```
exec /usr/bin/awesome --config /home/cscs/.config/awesome/rc.lua >> ~/.cache/awesome/stdout 2 >> ~/.cache/awesome/stderr
```

Is there an [other way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/preventing-access-to-tty-when-x-is-killed) to implement this using `trap "" INT` somewhere? 
I had no success catching the CTRL+C sequence, my X server exited with the message: `unexpected signal 2`.

Login managers (slim, gdm, kdm, etc.) are not applicable.

Comment: Migrated on request of the OP. (Your question would have been fine to stay on [SU] as well, just FYI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `trap` here.
You actually want to make **xinit** run WITHOUT a terminal, thus making SIGINT to be avoided after CTRL-C.

Run X server like this:

```
startx & disown; exit
```

and edit /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config so that a specific user can run X.

Comment: With `zsh` and `bash`, you can do this instead: `startx &! exit`. I believe other shells--I'm not sure which ones--support this syntax as well.